# What mean $(B_{\tau\wedge t})_{t\geq 0}$ is a $L^2$-Cauchy sequence where $\tau$ is a stoping time and $(B_t)$ a brownian motion

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

In the Book "Brownian motion" of Schilling and Partzsch, to prove that $\mathbb E[B_\tau^2]=\mathbb E[\tau]$ whenever $\mathbb E[\tau]<\infty $, they proved that $$(B_{\tau\wedge t})_{t\geq 0},$$
is a $L^2-$Cauchy sequence.

What does this mean since $(B_{\tau\wedge t})_{t\geq 0}$ is even not a sequence ?

I mean, if $n\in\mathbb N$, then $(B_{\tau\wedge n})_n$ is a $L^2-$Cauchy sequence means that $$\lim_{m,n\to \infty }\mathbb E[(B_{\tau\wedge n}-B_{\tau\wedge m})^2]=0,$$

but what does it mean for a continuous process $(B_{\tau\wedge t})_{t\geq 0}$ ? Maybe that $(B_{\tau\wedge t_n})_n$ is a Cauchy sequence for all $(t_n)$ s.t. $t_n\to \infty $ when $n\to \infty $ ?

So, for people who are interested by the proof

[image]
[image]

Comment: Perhaps include part of the "proof" of this statement? I agree that it doesn't make sense considering that the process in question is not a sequence.

Comment: @Math1000: I add the proof :)

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are talking about the proof of Theorem 5.10.

You're right, they are being a little bit sloppy.  They are thinking of the limit as $t \to \infty$ as a "sequence", even though the limit should be taken through all the reals.

However, it is easy to fix.  Let $t_n$ be any increasing sequence of real numbers which tends to infinity.  Then their argument shows that $\{B_{\tau \wedge t_n}\}$ is an $L^2$-Cauchy sequence, and therefore converges to some random variable which we may call $B_\tau$.  Moreover, if $t_n'$ is any other increasing sequence which also tends to infinity, their argument also shows that $B_{\tau \wedge t_n} - B_{\tau \wedge t_n'}$ converges to 0 in $L^2$, hence $B_{\tau \wedge t_n'}$ also converges in $L^2$ to the same $B_\tau$.

To finish, we check that indeed $B_{\tau \wedge t} \to B_\tau$ in $L^2$, in the usual sense of limits through the reals: for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $M > 0$ such that for all $t > M$ we have $\|B_{\tau \wedge t} - B_\tau\|_{L^2} < \epsilon$.  For suppose not.  Taking $M = 0$ we can find some $t_1 > 0$ such that $\|B_{\tau \wedge t_1} - B_\tau\|_{L^2} \ge \epsilon$.  Taking $M=\max(t_1,1)$ we can find $t_2 > M$ with the same property.  Continuing in this way, with $M = \max(t_n, n)$, we find a sequence $t_n$ which is strictly increasing and tends to infinity, such that $\|B_{\tau \wedge t_n} - B_\tau\|_{L^2} \ge \epsilon$ for every $n$, which contradicts the conclusion of the previous paragraph.

This is a good type of argument to know, because it is commonly used to apply results about sequences to limits through the reals.

Comment: Well, acctually, if for all sequence $(t_n)$ s.t. $B_{\tau\wedge t_n}\to B_{\tau}$ in $L^2$ when $n\to \infty $, obviously $B_{\tau\wedge t}\to B_{\tau}$ in $L^2$ sense when $t\to \infty $, no ? A priori this is a very standard result, no ? Also, in the first part, why do you introduce $(t_n')$ ? Because now I'm confuse : to says that $(B_{\tau\wedge t})_{t\geq 0}$ is $L^2$ Cauchy wouldn't mean that $(B_{\tau\wedge t_n})_n$ is $L^2-$Cauchy for all $(t_n)$ s.t. $t_n\to \infty $ ?

Comment: @John: Yes, it's pretty standard, and all I did was to write out a proof of this standard fact, since I couldn't tell from your question whether you already knew it.  As for the $t_n'$: it's true that for every sequence $t_n$ with $t_n \to \infty$, the sequence $B_{\tau \wedge t_n}$ is $L^2$-Cauchy, and therefore converges to some random variable.  But *a priori*, it is possible that if I choose a different sequence $t_n'$, I get convergence to a *different* random variable.  So we need to rule that out and show that the limit is really well defined.

Comment: Thanks for this proof. It makes sense out of the ill-defined statement in the original question :)